# Spring MVC forwarding parameters not picked up

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to forward requests to another controller.

My controller method has a return statement:

```
return "forward:/v1/user/"+redirectPath;
```

From experience with redirects, this is very bad because then the views don't get cached and I will have memory problems.

However, I've tried using RequestAttributes as so:

```
requestAttr.addAttribute("redirectPath", redirectPath);
return "forward:/v1/user/{redirectPath}";
```

However, this doesn't get picked up by Spring MVC, it doesn't substitute redirectPath in the redirected URL.

Any suggestions?

Comment: sorry not clear, when you are forwarding to a different controller what does redirectPath contains ?

Comment: redirectPath contains a string, for example, I would pass in an id, like so:

When a person visits url `/v2/user/1` I would chop the front of the expression and extract `String redirectPath = "1"`. Then, I would forward this to another controller, which should be concatenated into `forward:/v1/user/1`.